# How to set condition on the time frame of local user?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-packages

This is an app called Taskify on which I'm working on. It's my first major project and I want to know if there's any way to implement condition on the local user's time.
What I want is to change the tag to "on processed" if the time is still there after the completion of previous task.

[image: App UI]

```
class TaskOverviewCard extends StatefulWidget {
  late String subtaskName;
  late TimeOfDay endTime;
  final now = TimeOfDay.now();

  TaskOverviewCard(
      {super.key, required this.subtaskName, required this.endTime});

  @override
  State<TaskOverviewCard> createState() => _TaskOverviewCardState();
}

class _TaskOverviewCardState extends State<TaskOverviewCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late Size mq = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
            height: mq.height * 0.154,
            width: mq.width * 0.9,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0, right: 16),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          widget.subtaskName,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                        ),
                        const Icon(Icons.more_horiz)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 18, top: 20),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        width: 400,
                        height: 50,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.schedule,
                                    size: 18,
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Text(endTime.format(context))
                                ],
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 7, vertical: 3),
                                    child: (endTime.hour < now.hour &&
                                            endTime.minute < now.minute)
                                        ? taskCompleted()
                                        : taskNotCompleted()),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm not getting desired results.

Comment: Where do the variables `endTime` and `now` come from? Can you show us that bit of the code? Also, can you explain with a little bit more detail what you are trying to achieve? Thx.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the code. Please take a look. I want to change the tag of completed to on processed if time has not passed yet. For example, if user has set a deadline of 8:00 AM and the next task is scheduled at 10:00 AM, and the current time is 9:00 AM or any time between 8' o clock and 10' o clock then the tag should be on processed. I hope you're getting  what I want to say. Any type of help is appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me describe how I understand your problem, if this is wrong, please correct me.
You want to show "Not Completed" if the user's time is before the `endTime` of the current task. If the user's time is between the `endTime` of the current task and the next task, the text should be changed to "On processed", and if the user's time is after the next `endTime`, it should say completed.

To figure out if the local time of the user is after the not only need the `endTime?` of this task, but also the `endTime` of the next task. For that, in your `class TaskOverviewCard`, you have to add a variable:

```
final DateTime nextTaskEndTime;
```

and declare it in the constructor accordingly. Then, you can use methods like [isBefore](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/isBefore.html) etc., and show the correct text according to the current time.

A few other things:

1. I don't see why your widget needs to be stateful. Please use stateless as it makes the implementation easier.
2. Why are your variables `late`? Consider making them `final` instead, as this is required by stateless widgets, and these variables should never change anyways.
3. I would put the logic with the time in a different method. I have drafted out some code for you:

```
class TaskOverviewCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String subtaskName;
  final DateTime endTime;
  final DateTime nextTaskEndTime;
  final now = DateTime.now();

  TaskOverviewCard({super.key, required this.subtaskName, required this.endTime, required this.nextTaskEndTime});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //TODO: Put your Widget here, use the method buildTaskStateWidget() where the task state should be displayed
  }

  Widget buildTaskStateWidget() {
  //Here, use endTime, nextTaskEndTime, and now to figure out what should be displayed
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. If there is anything unclear please do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: "I don't see why your widget needs to be stateful. Please use stateless as performance-wise, it is way better, and makes the implementation easier.".  What?  No.  Use stateful when you have state, and stateless otherwise.  Performance should not be a consideration.

Comment: Of course performance is a consideration, if stateful were performing better (which it isn't) you would use it! But there is not state here and the reason to switch to stateless is of course performance, otherwise it just wouldn't matter!

Comment: I'm challenging "way better" though.  Pretty sure any performance difference is negligible.

Comment: You're probably right about that. I've edited the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that chunk helped me through.